# [number]-F appearing at the end of String?

Tags: c++

I am a new to c++ and was butchering together a palindrome program at 1am on a Sunday just, because! and I have come across this problem:

Input: test
Reverse: tset3-F

Where has the 3-F come from? Sometimes it's just -F or another number-F. Where is this coming from?

Here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>


 using namespace std;

int main() {

 string eString;

 int length;
 int counter = 0;

 cout << "Enter String: ";
 cin >> eString;

 length = eString.length();


 char reverseChar[length];




  for(int x = eString.length() -1; x > -1; x--) {

     reverseChar[counter] = eString[x];

     counter++;

 }
 cout << "Reverse: " << reverseChar;


  }
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: By the way, you can use `std::reverse` for this purpose exactly. Not even any need for C strings.

Comment: Thank you, looking into it now. My accelerated C++ book has not arrived so I am kind of winging it until then to get a bit of practice! Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Aside*: `char reverseChar[length];` isn't valid C++. Some compilers accept variable-length arrays as a language extension, but C++ requires all arrays to be constant length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't adding a null terminator to the end of your strings. It's random data that happens to be in memory.

reverseChar should be length + 1 in size

The final char should be set to '\0'

reverseChar[length] = '\0';

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: Sorry, I've not delved into memory management as of yet, how do I add a null terminator?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and link, reading through it now. Out of curiosity, I see a lot of code involving chars and now I've faced this problem it's apparent why Strings are not favoured in c++, could you briefly go over how I could do this using char's?

Comment: @speakon It's char arrays that are not favored in c++, and things are easier if you use just `std::string`s.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a null terminator to the `reverseChar` string.  There is a 0 just after the last character of all strings in C, which tells string manipulation functions where the string ends in memory.  The 0 is never included in the length, so you have to remember to add room for it when allocating space for a string.

```
char reverseChar[length + 1]; 

for(int x = eString.length() -1; x > -1; x--) { 

     reverseChar[counter] = eString[x]; 
     counter++; 

} 

reverseChar[length] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think: char reverseChar[length+1] because you need to leave space for the end of string delimiter reverseChar[length]='\0'